# VBA - Rearrange data in new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and could not find a thread to answer this already. Apologies if duplicate.

I have 2 sheets in an Excel file called "sheet1" and "sheet2". "sheet1" has 50,000+ rows like this: (if it were sorted by "username" then "question")

```
username   |question   |answer    | ...many other columns...
Mr_1754    |Q10        |56        |
Mr_1754    |Q18        |32        |
Mr_1754    |Q56        |42        |
Mr_9564    |Q10        |1         |
Mr_9564    |Q22        |564       |
...
```

That is, each row has a unique question and username combination. Note that usernames are essentially random numbers following "Mr_" and question numbers are also arbitrary. The "answer" column only contains integers. Different usernames have different numbers of questions. What I want to do is create a spreadsheet that looks like the one below, in "sheet2":

```
username   |Q10       |Q18       |Q22       |Q56       | ...as many columns as there are questions...
Mr_1754    |56        |32        |          |42        |
Mr_9564    |1         |          |564       |          |
...As many rows as there are usernames...
```

That is, I want to put each username in its own row with blanks for any questions that username did not answer.

Any suggested code will be most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. [Have you already tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) People are more eager to help if you show some research effort before asking. Otherwise, you will appear as a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Comment: In addition to showing us results of your own research, you should also explain the significance of "...many other columns..." in your source data example.  Do you have multiple sets of three columns?  Or can those "...many other columns..." be ignored, as you are only interested in the first three?

Comment: Thanks for replies. no, the "many other columns" may be ignored, just wanted to note they are there. I tried a few things, but I am far from getting there, so I did not include.

Comment: Post what you have done; the algorithm you are using; and where you are running into trouble.  Also see HELP for advice on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer could be pretty easy if you don't need specifically VBA. Pivot table could give you the exact data you need. You should:

- select all the data in sheet1
- choose Insert->Pivot table
- place the `username` field in the row labels area
- place the `question` in the column labels area
- place `answer` in values area

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I did not know about "pivot table". Following your steps then choosing "product" or "sum" from "Summarize values by" when right-clicking on the resulting data did the trick. I assume "product" and "sum" worked because every username & question combination was unique. Thanks again.